# Setting thumbnail featured image size not working properly

Tags: theme-development

Hi I just started today on creating my first Wordpress Theme and I am trying to create a featured Image for each post.Aldo I have managed to acomplish that it seems that the sizes I am giving it are not taking effect.Here is my code:

```
if(function_exists('add_theme_support')){
   add_theme_support('post-thumbnails' , array('post'));
   set_post_thumbnail_size(200,120);
}

if(function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail()){
      the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

It seems that my featured images are not always set to the same size.For example if the image is smaller then what size I set it will remain the same , for big images the width is the same but for some the height is different.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's default behaviour that the images aren't scaled up. Easiest way would be to use simple CSS to scale it up.

[How to scale up featured post thumbnail?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50649/how-to-scale-up-featured-post-thumbnail)

For the second part set the `crop` parameter of `set_post_thumbnail_size` to true.

```
set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 120, true );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size