# How to crop image in WordPress with aspect ratio for any size of image

Tags: functions, customization, images, cropping

I am using following function for cropping image in wordpress and I want to crop image in 1:1 aspect ratio. When I upload large image compared to specified size in function it works well but when I upload smaller image compare to specified in function size it does not produce 1:1 but it takes height or width that fits best and produce image in other aspect ratio.

```
add_image_size('member-photo', 200, 200, true);
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

But I need 1:1 image in ratio so when ever user upload any size of image it cropped in that ratio.

Note: I don't want to use different sizes of images.

Comment: You can hook [image_resize_dimensions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/64953/3276) to customise how crops and scaling are calculated. You probably just want to make the logic conditional on your 200x200 sizes, or pass a string as the crop parameter and detect that, so that the normal code is used for all other thumbnails.

Comment: @rup This function works well. Thanks